# Android Change Settings of Create New Project (Default Settings)?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have installed new version of Android Studio. And also download sdk for API 23. I would like to change default settings of project while creating new project. When i created new project it always create new project with,

```
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"
```

i know how to change it later, but i have to change it every time. i want to create new project with

```
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion '22.0.1'
```

Comment: it is usually part of the "new project wizard". Do you have installed more versions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is based on the SDK platforms that you have installed. In SDK Manager->SDK platforms you can see what are all the SDK you have,it will choose the max sdk from that.